# SaveFileDialog makes application freeze on close

Tags: vb.net, winforms, openfiledialog

I experience a wierd problem with `SafeFileDialog`: When used, application can't be closed properly and hangs in Background Processes in Task Manager, where I have to kill it (and it takes like 10 minutes before Windows kills it).

```
    Try
        SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt*)|*.txt|Report file (*.rpt)|*.rpt"
        If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR during saving report file. " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

No error or output message is produced and it seem to work as intended otherwise ("Hello World" is written into output).

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is that code located?

Comment: What kind of application is this? WinForms? Console app?

Comment: A mis-behaving shell extension is almost always the cause.  Programmers' machines tend to have a lot of them, not always of the best quality.  Use SysInternals' AutoRuns utility to identify the troublemaker.  Start by disabling all that don't have a Microsoft copyright, re-enable them one by one in the order of usefulness until you reproduced the problem.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Just in a Button.click handler.

Comment: @41686d6564 Sorry, WinForms, added into tags.

Comment: @HansPassant OK, that will need little bit of studying and trying. Thank you for a suggestion, I will report if I find anything.

Comment: I couldn't find anything pointing to a problem, even with my colleague. I gave up and removed SaveFileDialog from the solution, using some default path that a user can change in a TextBox. Doesn't really impact usability of this tiny tool.